# How to solve this transient circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Could anyone explain why in this example \$ I_t = (\frac{12}{5} - \frac{24}{2})\$? It is my understanding that it should be \$\frac{12}{5}\$ because of the initial condition of natural response.

[image]

Comment: Look, \$\frac{24\:\text{V}}{2\:\Omega}=12\:\text{A}\$ is clearly the result at \$t=\infty\$. At \$t=0\$, it is clearly \$\frac{12\:\text{V}}{5\:\Omega}=2.4\:\text{A}\$. In between times, it must vary between these two values. The equation you show has the \$t=\infty\$ value as the first term. It includes as the second term an exponential decay that occurs from \$t=0\$ to \$t=\infty\$. The factor in front of the exponential decay term is simply the difference between the starting and ending points. (The exponential factor itself starts at 1 and ends at 0 over that range.)

Comment: Don't put units inside anything but very simple equations as this gets really confusing, e.g.: \$\small I=12A-(9.6A)e^{-4t}\$ should be written: \$\small I=12-9.6e^{-4t}\:A\$